# How to do Multiple column count in SPARK/SCALA efficiently?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, count, group-by

I have a data frame from which I need counts of all the columns with filter (value > 0) for each column .

Right now I am doing :

```
   import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel._

    df.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)

    val totalCustomers = df.count

    val totalpurchaseCount = df.filter("totalpurchase > 0").count

    val totalRentsCount = df.filter("totalRent > 0").count

    val totalTVCount = df.filter("tvCount > 0").count

    val totalMovieCount = df.filter("movieCount  > 0").count

    val totalKidsCount = df.filter("kidsCount > 0 ").count

    val totalNonKidsCount = df.filter("adultsCount > 0").count
```

Is there any way to do this efficiently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a list of columns:

```
val cols = Seq("totalpurchase", "totalRent", ...)
```

Import required functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{count, col, when}
```

Select aggregates:

```
val aggs = df.select(cols.map(c => count(when(col(c) > 0, true)).alias(c)): _*)
```

Collect result and extract values.

```
aggs.first match {
  case row => (0 until cols.size).map(i => cols(i) -> row.getLong(i)).toMap
}
```